# Gitea Action fails to run and install yamllint

Tags: gitea

Trying to validate YAML files. Why is below code not able to work?

- Scenario 1:

  ```yaml
    validate-yaml:
      runs-on: python-test   ##  a python:latest image 
      steps:
        - run: pip install yamllint
        - run: yamllint  ../../.
  ```

  ```
  Error:  unable to reach pip
  ```
- Scenario 2:

  ```yaml
    validate-yaml:
      runs-on: python-lint   ## registry.gitlab.com/pipeline-components/yamllint:latest  an image with lini installed
      steps:
        - run: yamllint  ../../.
  ```

  ```
  Error: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
  ```